# Error Flutter: [sliver_list] 'estimatedMaxScrollOffset >= endScrollOffset - childScrollOffset(firstChild)': is not true

Tags: flutter, layout, flutter-sliver

I have the following error when I add a new item to my SliverList. This one nested in CustomScrollView which is it nested in a LiquidPullToRefresh (https://pub.dev/packages/liquid_pull_to_refresh) to update my list with the new items. The list is well updated but I still have this error.

Any ideas ?

**Error**

```
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
flutter: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart': Failed assertion: line 270 pos 14:
flutter: 'estimatedMaxScrollOffset >= endScrollOffset - childScrollOffset(firstChild)': is not true.
flutter:
flutter: Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
flutter: more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
flutter: In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
flutter:   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
flutter:
flutter: The relevant error-causing widget was:
flutter:   SliverList file:///Users/flo/Mobile/R-CUT/Dev/rcut/lib/src/views/home-views/ProfilView.dart:84:18
flutter:
flutter: When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
flutter: #2      RenderSliverList.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart:270:14)
flutter: #3      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
flutter: #4      RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:410:13)
flutter: #5      RenderViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1367:12)
flutter: #6      RenderViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1285:20)
flutter: #7      RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1584:7)
flutter: #8      PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:844:18)
flutter: #9      RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:344:19)
flutter: #10     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:774:13)
flutter: #11     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:283:5)
flutter: #12     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1102:15)
flutter: #13     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1041:9)
flutter: #14     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:957:5)
flutter: #18     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:259:10)
flutter: #19     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:217:3)
flutter: (elided 5 frames from class _AssertionError and package dart:async)
flutter:
flutter: The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderSliverList#0ac99 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE:
flutter:   needs compositing
flutter:   creator: SliverList ← FutureBuilder<dynamic> ← RCutFutureBuilder<void> ← Viewport ←
flutter:     IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#c0cdd] ← Semantics ← _PointerListener ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ←
flutter:     RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#5ef68] ← _PointerListener ← Listener
flutter:     ← ⋯
flutter:   parentData: paintOffset=Offset(0.0, 218.0) (can use size)
flutter:   constraints: SliverConstraints(AxisDirection.down, GrowthDirection.forward, ScrollDirection.idle,
flutter:     scrollOffset: 0.0, remainingPaintExtent: 424.6, crossAxisExtent: 375.0, crossAxisDirection:
flutter:     AxisDirection.right, viewportMainAxisExtent: 637.0, remainingCacheExtent: 674.6 cacheOrigin: 0.0 )
flutter:   geometry: SliverGeometry(scrollExtent: 4381.0, paintExtent: 419.0, maxPaintExtent: 4381.0,
flutter:     hasVisualOverflow: true, cacheExtent: 669.0)
flutter:   currently live children: 0 to 2
flutter: This RenderObject had the following descendants (showing up to depth 5):
flutter:     child with index 0: RenderIndexedSemantics#955fe relayoutBoundary=up2
flutter:       child: RenderRepaintBoundary#8a7b5 relayoutBoundary=up3
flutter:         child: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#81c7a relayoutBoundary=up4
flutter:           child: RenderPointerListener#7c025 relayoutBoundary=up5
flutter:             child: RenderTransform#bcf92 relayoutBoundary=up6
flutter:     child with index 1: RenderIndexedSemantics#675eb relayoutBoundary=up2
flutter:       child: RenderRepaintBoundary#e9121 relayoutBoundary=up3
flutter:         child: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#5ac06 relayoutBoundary=up4
flutter:           child: RenderPointerListener#7550a relayoutBoundary=up5
flutter:             child: RenderTransform#64638 relayoutBoundary=up6
flutter:     child with index 2: RenderIndexedSemantics#cdfbd relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
flutter:       child: RenderRepaintBoundary#490ab relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
flutter:         child: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#116b6 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
flutter:           child: RenderPointerListener#30856 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
flutter:             child: RenderTransform#8a669 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
flutter: ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart': Failed assertion: line 270 pos 14: 'estimatedMaxScrollOffset >= endScrollOffset - childScrollOffset(firstChild)': is not true.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart': Failed assertion: line 270 pos 14: 'estimatedMaxScrollOffset >= endScrollOffset - childScrollOffset(firstChild)': is not true.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart': Failed assertion: line 270 pos 14: 'estimatedMaxScrollOffset >= endScrollOffset - childScrollOffset(firstChild)': is not true.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart': Failed assertion: line 270 pos 14: 'estimatedMaxScrollOffset >= endScrollOffset - childScrollOffset(firstChild)': is not true.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart': Failed assertion: line 270 pos 14: 'estimatedMaxScrollOffset >= endScrollOffset - childScrollOffset(firstChild)': is not true.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart': Failed assertion: line 270 pos 14: 'estimatedMaxScrollOffset >= endScrollOffset - childScrollOffset(firstChild)': is not true.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart': Failed assertion: line 270 pos 14: 'estimatedMaxScrollOffset >= endScrollOffset - childScrollOffset(firstChild)': is not true.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart': Failed assertion: line 270 pos 14: 'estimatedMaxScrollOffset >= endScrollOffset - childScrollOffset(firstChild)': is not true.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart': Failed assertion: line 270 pos 14: 'estimatedMaxScrollOffset >= endScrollOffset - childScrollOffset(firstChild)': is not true.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart': Failed assertion: line 270 pos 14: 'estimatedMaxScrollOffset >= endScrollOffset - childScrollOffset(firstChild)': is not true.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart': Failed assertion: line 270 pos 14: 'estimatedMaxScrollOffset >= endScrollOffset - childScrollOffset(firstChild)': is not true.
    [C20.1 72D7C5AF-3D0E-46BC-BC25-8ED1FCD9A4F6 192.168.0.2:50854<->216.58.197.170:443]
    Connected Path: satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0
    Duration: 70.736s, DNS @0.000s took 0.002s, TCP @0.003s took 0.034s, TLS took 0.086s
    bytes in/out: 5597/3006, packets in/out: 10/12, rtt: 0.089s, retransmitted packets: 0, out-of-order packets: 0
```

**Flutter doctor**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Mac OS X 10.15 19A602, locale en-FR)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.0)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.41.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give "itemExtent" value to your listview widget